# (Prove)/Disprove that if group A of order 4 is NOT cyclic, then its elements are their own inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification

I am having trouble seeing the relation between cyclic groups/subgroups and inverses; to my knowledge it's cyclic if it can be generated by a single element that spans it across a larger group, but I fail to see how inverses can be cleverly proved using the definition of cyclicism (being cyclic)

so lets suppose...

A is a group of size $4$, denoted $|A| = 4$ ; now prove that A is not cyclic, and then that every element of A is its own inverse

my idea:

A group of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if it has an element of order $n$, now using this definition we could (maybe) draw the conclusion that if our group is order 4 then it's element can't also have order 4 without being the entire group A itself and thus can't be cyclic (?). But then I'm not sure how inverses tie into this unfortunately....

any and all help is appreciated !!

Comment: Up to isomorphism, there are only two groups of order $4$

Comment: You do not “prove that $A$ is not cyclic.” You are **assuming** that $A$ is not cyclic. that means that if $a\in A$ is any element, then the subgroup generated by $a$ is not all of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct intuition. Now, combine the definition of the order of an element and the definition of the inverse, and you're done.

Comment: so this would be to say that the order of an element is the least positive integer that produces the identity, and when it comes to a non-cyclic group the order of it's elements are themselves thus making them their own inverses (since an inverse is what can be applied to an element to produce the identity)?

Comment: Not exactly: in this particular case, the group has order 4. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element has to divide 4: the possibilities are 1,2 and 4. If you additionally assume that the groupe is not cyclic, this rules out 4. So elements being their own inverse is really specific to this situation, as only elements of order at most two are like this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You have to convince yourself that, the remaining three elements apart from $e$ have order two because can't have order three neither four.

Answer (score 0):

As is well known, the only groups of order $4$ are $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.  Since we're ruling out the former, we have the latter, that is, the so called Klein four group, where everything but the identity has order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can prove it with a easy reasoning. Let $G$ be any group and let $g \in G$, we define the order of $g$ as $o(g):=\min\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid g^n=e\}$. We have the following easy facts.

- $\quad o(g)\leq |G|$.
- $\quad G$ is cyclic if there exists $g\in G$ such that $o(g)=|G|$.
- $\quad o(g)=1$ if and only if $g=e$.
- $\quad $ If $g\not=e$, then $o(g)=2$ if and only if $g^{-1}=g$.

Now, assume that $|G|=4$ and $G$ is non-cyclic. Thus, all elements of $G$ have order at most $3$.

Suppose that there exists $x \in G \setminus\{e\}$ such that $x\not=x^{-1}$. Then $o(x)>2$ and hence $o(x)=3$. Therefore, $G=\{e,x,x^2,y\}$, where $y\not \in \{e,x,x^2\}$. Since $o(x)=3$ we deduce that $x^{-1}=x^2$ and hence $xy\not=1$. If $xy=x$, then $y=e$, which is impossible. Analogously, if $xy=y$, then $x=e$, which is also impossible. Finally, if $xy=x^2$, then $y=x$, which is again a contradiction. Thus, $x=x^-1$ for all $x \in G\setminus\{e\}$ and the result follows.

You can make an easier proof using that the order of the elements must divide $|G|$. However, I prefered to give this elementary proof.